# Passing a label to a class in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, label

I am creating a hand tracking game where it takes an input from a camera, applies ML to show points on the fingers, and then actions can be performed based on the location of the fingers in the frame and the gesture.

I have a screen where the play will choose between two games. I want a modular approach as I will be wanting to using this webcam capture code multiple times for different game. So I want it to be its own file where I can just pass it a label from the current screen and It will show the video feed.

I can't get the video feed to show on a label I pass to the class.

Game choice screen -

```py
class gameChoice(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(1200, 850)
        self.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())

        self.label = QLabel('VIDEO GOES HERE')
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('border : 3px solid green;') # 

        # This is the class I want to call
        videoFeed(self.label)
        self.show()
```

Which produces:
[image]

This is the code for the video feed -

```py
class videoFeed(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.disply_width = 1200
        self.display_height = 850

        # create the label that holds the webcam video
        self.image_label = parent
        # The line above it important
        self.image_label.resize(self.disply_width, self.display_height)
        self.image_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setStyleSheet('border : 3px solid blue;')

        self.closeButton = QPushButton( "Close the video", clicked = lambda : self.closeVideo())
        self.closeButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.closeButton.setFont(QFont('Helvetica', 15))

        # create a vertical box layout and add the two labels
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.closeButton)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.image_label)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        # set the vbox layout as the widgets layout
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        # this is a method to actually show the webcam feed
        self.videoFeed = VideoThread()
```

I've passed the label I want to use and called it `parent` in the videoFeed class and reassigned it in the class.

Comment: A [QLabel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html) cannot display videos. Use the [Qt Multimedia classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-module.html) instead.

Comment: I'm converting the video to a pixmap and setting the label to that.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're exactly trying to achieve but, are you asking if you can put the *same* label in two different widgets? If that's the case, that's not possible; a widget is like a physical object: you can't put the same foot in two shoes. Since you're using pixmaps, create a new label for the video feed widget and just use `setPixmap()` on both labels.